# bash remove everything before character

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have the following:

```
netstat -tuna | awk '{ print $4; }' | sed -e '1,2d'
```

which returns:

```
10.20.26.143:51697
10.20.26.143:51696
10.20.26.143:51698
10.20.26.143:51693
10.20.26.143:51695
10.20.26.143:51694
:::22
0.0.0.0:68
0.0.0.0:49625
0.0.0.0:5353
:::48727
:::5353
```

which returns a list of all open ports.. how would i remove everything before the : character? please notice that a few ones have ::: instead of :
i just want it to return the ports, remove all text before the last :

i want it all in one bash command.

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

add to your sed-command:

```
';s/.*:/:/g'

netstat -tuna | awk '{ print $4; }' | sed -e '1,2d;s/.*:/:/g'
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with one awk command. No need to chain too many

```
netstat -tuna | awk  'NR>2{ k=split($4,a,":");print a[k] }'
```

or

```
netstat -tuna | awk  'NR>2{ sub(/.*:/,"",$4);print $4 }'
```

or Ruby(1.9+)

```
netstat -tuna | ruby -ane 'puts $F[3].sub(/.*:/,"") if $.>2'
```

if you want unique ports,

```
netstat -tuna | awk  'NR>2{ sub(/.*:/,"",$4); uniq[$4] }END{ for(i in uniq) print i }'
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, [you can tuna network, but you can't tuna fish](http://www.instantrimshot.com)

The following will print all open ports

```
netstat -tuna | awk -F':+| +' 'NR>2{print $5}'
```

The following will print all ***unique*** open ports, i.e. no duplicates sorted in ascending order

```
netstat -tuna | awk -F':+| +' 'NR>2{print $5}' | sort -nu
```